# Reorder spotify queue on android?

Tags: android, spotify, queue, queue-management

Is it possible to reorder the tracks in the queue, on the spotify android app?

I know this is possible on desktop by drag and dropping the track within the queue, but can't seem to find the feature on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not currently present in the Spotify Android client, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I hope its introduced one day, a very handy feature.

Comment: The Android developers at Spotify are aware of the limitation and the feature is in the backlog. So yeah, it could happen one day. :)